# plaintext passwords show up in http headers

Tags: .net, forms, security, passwords

I am helping test a .NET application that accepts a user's name and password. The application runs over SSL and is hosted via an iframe on a page that is also setup with SSL (so the user can see the https on the parent page and feel confident about entering information).

So, to be clear, there is a page https://www.mydomain.com/mypage.aspx and, inside that page, there is an iframe which references a .NET application on the same server as https://www.mydomain.com/apps/myapp.aspx

When the user submits the page, I am watching the headers via the Filezilla browser addon "Live HTTP Headers". To my dismay, the form data, including user name and password, is displayed in plaintext in the POST section of the headers.

My conclusion is that the information is not being encrypted. Is that correct? If so, what is the best solution?

Comment: the authentication mode for the application is "Forms".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are posting those form variables over https/SSL then the actual transmission will be encrypted. You'll be able to view them in the browser extension, but the browser will have to encrypt them to send them to the server via SSL so long as the post is actually posting to https:// not http://

You shouldn't then return the username password pair to the user but should then authenticate the user and then if it matches use something like forms authentication to generate a token that authenticates them for the current session.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your .net authentication is setup(windows, forms or passport), but authentication tickets are encrypted even without SSL being used.
SSL just secures the communication chanel between client(browser) and server.
From what you describe, it sounds like the form is just sending username/password fields as parameters via post or get without using using the .Net authentication features?

Here is good background on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Update: I re-read your questions: Its now clear to me that you're using .net Basic Authentication + SSL. This should work fine, as the SSL will cover you on the encryption part that is lacking in the Basic Authentication. You just need to make sure that the setup is correct. With respect to the FF add on, you're just looking at the info available to client(originator) and third party won't be able to do that.

Comment: If you are submitting the username and password in an HTML form they won't be encrypted in the post request. But they will be encrypted in SSL. Once the server has received them then you shouldn't be sending them back but using something like Forms authentication etc to manage the user from then on

Comment: so if they are not encrypted in the post request, is this something that can be sniffed?  i guess i'm not sure of the order of things (when the SSL happens).  i thought the post request was sent from client to server. So when does the SSL encryption kick in?  do i need to be concerned that i can see them in the post request plaintext...can others see them?      the application is using "Forms" as the authentication mode.